# If Statement with OnScreenText

Tags: python, text, hide, show, visible

I want to do a code where if a certain onscreen text is showing, then i want it to hide. I was going to try to do something like :

```
TTCloadingText = OnscreenText(text = "Heading to Toontown Central...", scale = .08, pos =     (-1.065, -.775, -.775), align=TextNode.ALeft, font = MickeyFont, fg=(0, 0, 0.5176470588235293,  1))
TTCloadingText.show()
if TTCloadingText.show = True Then
    TTCloadingText.hide()
```

Help please?

Answer (score 0):

Well, i think you need to review your python systax. "Then" is not an appropriate keyword to append the conditional "if" statement. Also, be sure you include ":".

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so below I believe I have fixed the code you provided. I will note the things I changed.

```
TTCloadingText = OnscreenText(text = "Heading to Toontown Central...", scale = .08, pos = (-1.065, -.775, -.775), align=TextNode.ALeft, font = MickeyFont, fg=(0, 0, 0.5176470588235293,  1))
TTCloadingText.show()
if TTCloadingText.show:
    TTCloadingText.hide()
```

I changed `if TTCloadingText.show = True Then` to `if TTCloadingText.show:` because python does not have a "Then" keyword; to get a "then" you use a `:`.

In your version, you had `if thing = True`, which would need to be `if thing == True`. Use `==` to test a variable/attribute.

Also, you do not need to use `== True`, because `if something:` works as `if something == True:` in python.

This may not be the perfect answer but it should definitely work. I have used Toontown coding for years and used a method like this before. Good luck!